# Problem shared element transition does not work between viewpage and recycleview when I select an other page in view page

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-animation, shared-element-transition

I have fragment adapter for recycle view and as we know for do shared element we have to settransitionName for image view in xml but in recyle view we set transition name programmatically for each one and in view page I set transition name in view page adapter for imageview that i want to apply shared element transition...

by the way, shared element work very well (when I click in image in recycle view the shared element work with image in view pager) but the main problem that why I post this question is when select an other image in view page,shared element does not work and it shared element transition with old image in recycle view (sorry about any lexial mistakes because english is not my original language).

Recycleview adapter:

```
public class GridAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GridAdapter.GridViewHolder> {

    int lastAnimatedPosition=-1;
    Context context;
    String[] data;
    AssetManager as;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    public GridAdapter(Context context,String[] data,AssetManager as, FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        this.context=context;
        this.data=data;
        this.as=as;
        this.fragmentManager=fragmentManager;
    }

    @Override
    public GridAdapter.GridViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chantion_gridview,parent,false);
        GridViewHolder Holder=new GridViewHolder(view);
        return Holder;
    }


    private void runEnterAnimation(View view, int position) {
        if (position >= data.length - 1) {
            return;
        }

        if (position > lastAnimatedPosition) {
            lastAnimatedPosition = position;
            view.setTranslationY(GlobalFunctions.getScreenHeight(view.getContext()));
            view.animate()
                    .translationY(0)
                    .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(3.f))
                    .setDuration(700)
                    .start();
        }
    }


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final GridAdapter.GridViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        //runEnterAnimation(holder.itemView, position);
        InputStream inputStream=null;
        try{

             inputStream=as.open("imagesTroll/"+position+".jpg");

        }catch (IOException io){

        }
        int width = 200;
        int height = 200;
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,height);
        holder.imageTroll.setLayoutParams(parms);
        holder.imageTroll.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream));
        holder.imageTroll.setTransitionName("transition"+position);
        holder.imageTroll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putStringArray("images",data);
                bundle.putInt("position",position);
                Fragment fragment=new FragmentViewPager();
                //setUp shared Element
                Transition transition=TransitionInflater.from(context)
                .inflateTransition(R.transition.mova);
                fragment.setSharedElementEnterTransition(transition);
                fragment.setSharedElementReturnTransition(transition);
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.content_frame,fragment)
                        .addSharedElement(holder.imageTroll, ViewCompat.getTransitionName(holder.imageTroll))
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.length;
    }




    class GridViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


        ImageButton imageTroll;


        public GridViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageTroll=itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        }

    }
}
```

viewpager adapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    String[] images;
    int position;
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    ViewPagerAdapter(Context context,String[] images,int position){
        this.context=context;
        this.images=images;
        this.position=position;
    }






    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.length;
    }
    public static int getScreenWidth() {
        return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    }

    public static int getScreenHeight() {
        return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.chantion_view_pager,container,false);


        AssetManager as=context.getAssets();
        ImageView imagePost=view.findViewById(R.id.imagePost);
        imagePost.setTransitionName("transition"+position);

        int width = getScreenWidth();
        int height = (int)(getScreenHeight()-getScreenHeight()*0.5);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,height);
        imagePost.setLayoutParams(parms);


        InputStream inputStream=null;
        try{

            inputStream=as.open("imagesTroll/"+position+".jpg");


        }catch (IOException io){

        }

        imagePost.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream));








        AdView adView = new AdView(context);
        AdSize adSize=new AdSize(getScreenWidth(),100);
        adView.setAdSize(adSize);
        adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");

        AdView mAdView = view.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object o) {
        return (view==(LinearLayout)o);
    }
}
```

I hope that any engineer helps me because this problem stops my processing.